# Losing session after a javascript redirect

Tags: php, session-variables, http-redirect

I have a html file basically calls a php file via ajax and if a login is successful, redirects the user to the index.php page via a redirect (window.location... etc.)

When the index.php loads it checks to see if a session variable is set and if not - redirects the user back to the login page. The problem is that even though the login is a success and the session variable has been set, it is no longer set when the index.php file is loaded. Please see image for overview of process.[image]

The problem is that even though the login is successful and the $_SESSION variable was successfully set, after the javascript redirect the session is reported as being not set.
I do include the session_start() directive in both php files. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Sorry for not including code - here is the code I am using 1st - the ajax request and redirect from html page

```
      function loginCompany(){

      let email = 'test@test.com';
      let pass ='124';
      
      if ((email =='') || (pass==''))
      {
          alert('Please enter a user name or email  and password');
           $('#email').focus();
          return;
      }
              $.ajax({   
          url: 'compAuth.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    async:true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                    email:email,
                    pass: pass,
                    userName : email
                    },
                    success: function (res) {
                        
                        if (res){
                            if (res.status == 'Success')
                                {   
                                 window.location.replace('index.php');
                                   return;                                                                    
                                   
                                 
                                }
                        else  {
                            console.log('not success : ');
 
                            if (res.status == 'Error') {
                               alert(res.description);
                            }
                            
                        }
                            
                            
                        }

                },// Success
                    error: function (res) {

                    }
           
                });
    

  }
```

Next is a snippet from Page B (the php script that sets the session and returns json results

```
  $response = [ 'status' => 'Success'];
    session_start(); 
     $_SESSION['dbname']  = $row['dbname'];
    echo json_encode($response);
```

And lastly - Page C which is called after a redirect from the initial HTML page (page A)

```
session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['dbname'])) {
    header("location: login.php");
```

So its this last page (page C the index,php file) that does not see the $_SESSION variable as being set

Many thanks..
Paul.
P.S Also just to say that there is no cross-domain traffic  - its all on the same domain :) Thanks.

Comment: We need some source code to help buddy

Comment: Is the AJAX call on the same exact domain? (even www vs. non-www or http vs. https would matter)

Comment: make sure you pass a session cookie with the ajax request (or csrf token)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the feedback - I have added the code to my post and yes - all this is happening on the same domain. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours of destructive testing, it seems that the problem was with one of my required php files. It seems there was an error in one of the files but instead of generating an error - it just stopped the session variable from being set. Does not seem logical but at this point - I am just happy its working. I am new to this and assumed I was just "getting it wrong". Sorry for wasting peoples time and thanks for the feedback.

Paul.